# Python: Parse file for a string and return value as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do, check if line in a config file contains a string (`'string1'`) or not, and if so then print the string and a found message (`'Found string1'`). I need to store the found message as a variable.

The problem is exactly here (I don't have any results for `print(line)` and for `print('Found string1')`:

```
def get_version():
    logger.info('Started')
    for file in os.listdir(running_config_dir):
        if file.endswith('.config'):
            for line in file:
                if str('string1') in line:
                    print(line)
                    print('Found string1')
        else:
            logger.critical('Running Configuration not found')

    logger.info('Finished')
```

Here is my config file,

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` is a *string*, containing a filename. As such, iterating over the string gives you individual characters, *not* the contents of the file:

```
>>> file = 'foo'
>>> for line in file:
...     print(line)
... 
f
o
o
```

You need to *open* the filename to get a file object:

```
with open(file) as fileobj:
    for line in fileobj:
```

Note that the `'...'` literal string syntax already produces a string object, there is no need to pass that to a `str()` call.

I'm not sure by what you mean with storing the found message as a variable; you already have access to the `line` variable, so you could just return that:

```
def get_version():
    logger.info('Started')
    version = None
    for file in os.listdir(running_config_dir):
        if file.endswith('.config'):
            with open(file) as fileobj:
                for line in fileobj:
                    if 'string1' in line:
                        print(line)
                        print('Found string1')
                        version = line.strip()
        else:
            logger.critical('Running Configuration not found')

    logger.info('Finished')
    return version
```